# Outline a 3D model correctly

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

I'm currently working on a simple 3D select Screen using SharpGL. It looks like this:

[image: Puzzle without outlines]

So far it looks allright, but I need to get it the puzzles outlined somehow, so it looks more like this:

[image: Puzzle with outlines]

I tried increasing the space between the individual puzzles, but it looks very ugly.
Does someone has another idea how to outline the individual puzzles?
Different colored puzzles is unfortunately out of the question.

Heres the Pic with the Spaces between the geometry:
http://oi59.tinypic.com/smc6sl.jpg

I used a Shader for the lighting, because it looks a bit better.

Heres the Blender wireframe:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/6yljis.jpg

Comment: How are you drawing this at the moment? Shader, fix-function, etc? Are the labels textures? Are the puzzle pieces separate chunks of geometry? Could you post a wireframe?

Comment: "but it looks very ugly" can you post an image of this too? Maybe its just a matter of colouring the sides correctly. E.g. you could have a little orange to black gradient to fake ambient occlusion and shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should draw lines by yourself using GL_LINES.

```
gl.LineWidth(3.0f);
gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_LINES);
gl.Vertex3(2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
gl.Vertex3(2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
...
gl.End();
```

Comment: glBegin, glVertex(), etc are **very** deprecated and should not be used in new development.

Comment: I didn't even know OpenGL could draw lines. Ok, thx Il try it tomorrow, its almost 22.30 over here.